A confusion about Karnaugh Map
Consider the following four variable Boolean function:
$$F(A,B,C,D)=\sum(0,2,3,5,7,8,9,10,11,13,15)$$
If I show you the map, then what I get is:

I have marked the Essential Prime Implicants with a bluer shade, which is $BD$ and $B'D'$. Then if I consider the prime implicants, there are four that I can get, which is:

So basically, from these four ways, there can be four such combinations in which I can consider the 1's from these K-map, taking two at a time. Thus, the above Boolean function evaluates to the expression:
$$F=BD+B'D'+CD+AD$$
$$F=BD+B'D'+CD+AB'$$
$$F=BD+B'D'+B'C+AD$$
$$F=BD+B'D'+B'C+AB'$$
But, If I consider the zeros only to apply POS, instead of SOP, this is what I arrive at:

Now, the expression is:
$$F=(B'+D)(A+B+C+D')$$
$$=AB'+B'C+B'D'+AD+BD+CD$$
Now, there are few questions of mine. I can see that the expression from POS is simply the sum of all of the four expressions from SOP. Why is so? Does not it make the SOP expression more simplified than POS? If it does, why is not SOP a better alternative of POS? Moreover, why does POS make more terms here than SOP? They are supposed to be interchangeable.

"POS is simply the sum of all of the four expressions from POS" - de Morgan applied to the POS yields a SOP containing all of the four non-essential prime implicants? (all prime implicants…)

Actually, I meant "POS is simply the sum of all of the four expressions from SOP". Could you explain a bit what you meant by the next statement?

I was just trying to make head or tail of the sentence. I can see it yields "simply the sum of all of the four expressions from SOP with occurrences of each product reduced to a single one. You may want to show an intermediate step, or find a slick formulation (reduced? canonical?).

Yes, I can see from the example that de Morgan applied to the POS yields a SOP containing all of the four non-essential prime implicants. But why is so?

@greybeard is there any way, you can help me with this?

Not personally, I'm afraid. One option I see is asking a math question about this.
